# How to insert multiple columns with different select conditions into another table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Simply I have two tables `ForecastBackup`,`ForecastTotal`
I want to select 4 columns from `ForecasTotal` table and insert into `ForecastBackup`

for example 
`ForecastTotal`

```
UCPVol  UCPVal  IBNSINAVol  IBNSINAVal
1         1      NULL        NULL
2         3      NULL        NULL
NULL     NULL    1            4
NULL     NULL    3            5
NULL     NULL    1            6
```

I want to insert into `ForecastBackup` non null values 
I mean result should be

```
UCPVol  UCPVal  IBNSINAVol  IBNSINAVal
    1         1      1            4
    2         3      3            5
    NULL     NULL    1            6
```

I used this SQL command but doesn't work

```
    INSERT INTO
    ForecastBackup (UCPVol,UCPVal,IBNSINAVol,IBNSINAVal)
    SELECT (select UCPVol,UCPVal from ForecastTotal where UCPVol is not null),
    (select IBNSINAVol,IBNSINAVal from ForecastTotal where IBNSINAVal is not null)
 from ForecastTotal
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Don't you need to union the two selects?

Comment: yes two select with different where conditions

Comment: @AmrKamal is there any relation between these two columns UCPVal   and IBNSINAVol

Comment: no but both in the same table

Comment: then I think your expectation need to change because with out any relation you can't show them in a row.

Comment: can't select non null values ?

Comment: You can select non null values.But see your output format there you put UCPVol,  UCPV values with non null values of IBNSINAVol,  IBNSINAVal in a single row. so with out any relation how it is possible. I thought there is a relation between UCPVal, IBNSINAVol . thats why i used self table left join. If you want records set in a single row you should have a relation between columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142720/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-amr-kamal).

Comment: ok i'm here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your input and out I think you need this query

```
INSERT INTO ForecastBackup (UCPVol,UCPVal, IBNSINAVol, IBNSINAVal) 
    SELECT
        A.UCPVol, A.UCPVal, B.IBNSINAVol, B.IBNSINAVal  
    FROM 
        ForecastTotal A
    LEFT JOIN
        ForecastTotal B ON A.UCPVal = B.IBNSINAVol
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO column_1 ( val_1, val_from_other_table ) 
VALUES('val_1', (SELECT  val_2 FROM table_2 WHERE val_2 = something))
```

Comment: I want to insert 4 values from one table to another one .. not different values from another tables

Comment: You can try with dynamic sql. Based on your conditions you can construct different statment. With loop statment get all the needed columns and check UCPVol/IBNSINAVal is null and construct insert like string and execute it.